# Digit gets cut off when using for loop to save number in character array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that calculates the rows of pascals triangle and to create a string that saves it. everything works fine until the columns include 2 digit numbers. Then, the second digit gets cut off.

However, when I use the sprintf function seperately, without a for loop or a if else statement, the number gets saved correctly.

```
char* pascal( int* n ) {

       int r = *n;
       int t = 0;
       int i;

       char res[MAX];

       for ( t = *n, i = 0; t >= 0; t--, i++ ) {
               if ( t == *n || t == 0 ) {
                       sprintf(&res[i], "%d", 1);
               } else {
                       sprintf(&res[i], "%d", fact(r)/(fact(t) * fact((r - t)));
               }
         }

         char* output = res;

         return output;

}
```

When I input 5 to the function I get:
151151

what I expect:
15101051

It's the same with every pascal row, that has colums that include numbers with 2 or more digits.

Comment: You increment `i` by only 1 each iteration.  But if you print an N digit number, you need to increment by N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, you are only incrementing the location of each number by 1, even though you may be printing a number with more than 1 digit. Try printing to a temporary string, then appending that to your 'answer:

```
char* pascal(int* n) {
    int r = *n;
    int t = 0;

    char res[MAX] = "";

    for (t = *n; t >= 0; t--) {
        char append[20]; // Assuming no more than 20 digits per number!
        if (t == *n || t == 0) {
            sprintf(append, "%d", 1);
        }
        else {
            sprintf(append, "%d", fact(r) / (fact(t) * fact((r - t))));
        }
        strcat(res, append);
    }

    char* output = res;

    return output;
}
```

But, actually, the excellent answer given by **Antii** is perhaps simpler.

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` returns the number of characters "output". Add the return value to `i` *instead* of just incrementing it by 1 in `i++`:

```
i += sprintf(&res[i], "%d", ...);
```

Comment: I expect this to be faster then using `strcat` because `strcat` has to go through all the string each time.